# How to work around duplicate symbol error when using Yesod and Darcs library?

Tags: haskell, yesod, darcs

It seems impossible to use Yesod together with the Darcs library due to a linker problem. I tracked down the problem and need hints to work around it by people familiar with Darcs internals.

When using the [darcs library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/darcs) in a [Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/) application, I get the following error:

```
GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   sha256_init
whilst processing object file
   /home/sebfisch/.cabal/lib/darcs-2.9.5/ghc-7.4.2/libHSdarcs-2.9.5.a
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

It appears to be caused by the darcs and [cryptohash](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptohash) libraries exposing the same symbol, as searching through the respective object files reveals:

```
# for file in `find ~/.cabal/lib/ -name "*.a"`; do (readelf -s $file | grep -i sha256_init) && (echo $file; echo); done
   293: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND sha256_init
    17: 0000000000000690    94 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 sha256_init
~/.cabal/lib/cryptohash-0.7.5/ghc-7.4.2/libHScryptohash-0.7.5.a

    10: 0000000000000290    45 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 sha256_init
~/.cabal/lib/darcs-2.8.2/ghc-7.4.2/libHSdarcs-2.8.2.a
```

I wrote a test program to confirm that the darcs and cryptohash libraries are in conflict:

```
import           Crypt.SHA256          (sha256sum)
import           Crypto.Hash.SHA256    (hash)
import           Data.ByteString       (empty)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

main :: IO ()
main = do
    BS.putStrLn $ hash empty    -- cryptohash
    putStrLn $ sha256sum empty  -- darcs
```

It fails to compile with a similar error:

```
/home/sebfisch/.cabal/lib/cryptohash-0.7.5/ghc-7.4.2/libHScryptohash-0.7.5.a(sha256.o): In function `sha256_update': sha256.c:(.text+0x4b0): multiple definition of `sha256_update'
/home/sebfisch/.cabal/lib/darcs-2.8.2/ghc-7.4.2/libHSdarcs-2.8.2.a(sha2.o):sha2.c:(.text+0xf90): first defined here
/home/sebfisch/.cabal/lib/cryptohash-0.7.5/ghc-7.4.2/libHScryptohash-0.7.5.a(sha256.o): In function `sha224_update': sha256.c:(.text+0x640): multiple definition of `sha224_update'
/home/sebfisch/.cabal/lib/darcs-2.8.2/ghc-7.4.2/libHSdarcs-2.8.2.a(sha2.o):sha2.c:(.text+0xbb0): first defined here
/home/sebfisch/.cabal/lib/cryptohash-0.7.5/ghc-7.4.2/libHScryptohash-0.7.5.a(sha256.o): In function `sha256_init': sha256.c:(.text+0x690): multiple definition of `sha256_init'
/home/sebfisch/.cabal/lib/darcs-2.8.2/ghc-7.4.2/libHSdarcs-2.8.2.a(sha2.o):sha2.c (.text+0x290): first defined here
/home/sebfisch/.cabal/lib/cryptohash-0.7.5/ghc-7.4.2/libHScryptohash-0.7.5.a(sha256.o): In function `sha224_init': sha256.c:(.text+0x6f0): multiple definition of `sha224_init'
/home/sebfisch/.cabal/lib/darcs-2.8.2/ghc-7.4.2/libHSdarcs-2.8.2.a(sha2.o):sha2.c (.text+0x620): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The cryptohash library is required by [yesod-static](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-static) and cannot easily be avoided when writing a Yesod application. How can I use Yesod and Darcs (as a library) in the same application?

Would it help to delete the duplicate symbols from one library? Both packages access hashing functions via FFI but using different files.

From [darcs/Crypt.SHA256](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/darcs/2.8.2/doc/html/src/Crypt-SHA256.html):

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "sha2.h sha256" c_sha256
    :: Ptr CChar -> CSize -> Ptr Word8 -> IO ()
```

From [cryptohash/Crypto.Hash.SHA256](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cryptohash/0.7.6/doc/html/src/Crypto-Hash-SHA256.html):

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "sha256.h sha256_init"
    c_sha256_init :: Ptr Ctx -> IO ()

foreign import ccall "sha256.h sha256_update"
    c_sha256_update :: Ptr Ctx -> CString -> Word32 -> IO ()

foreign import ccall unsafe "sha256.h sha256_finalize"
    c_sha256_finalize :: Ptr Ctx -> CString -> IO ()
```

Another idea is to rewrite Darcs to not use its own hashing function. How can I reimplement Darcs's `SHA256` module to use cryptohash? The two statements in the `main` function of my test program do not give the same output (tested by commenting out the other statement), so using cryptohash in Darcs does not seem entirely straightforward.

Comment: Can't you just rename the Darcs version of this function to something like `darcs_sha256_init`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that the symbol is defined in two different C files used via FFI, so renaming the Haskell function would not help, right?

Comment: However renaming the C function does help. See my revised answer.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the C files are included in the package and can be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The darcs hash output is just the base16 encoded version of the cryptohash output. Looks like [base16-bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base16-bytestring) is one way to bridge that gap. I tried it and Crypt.SHA256 becomes as simple as:

```
module Crypt.SHA256 ( sha256sum ) where

import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 ( hash )
import Data.ByteString ( ByteString )
import Data.ByteString.Base16 ( encode )
import Data.ByteString.Char8 ( unpack )

sha256sum :: ByteString -> String
sha256sum = unpack . encode . hash
```

In fact the [hashed-storage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashed-storage-0.5.10) package also has a copy of sha2.c and fixed the problem by renaming the symbols. So the simplest quick fix for darcs 2.8 is to copy [sha2.h](http://repos.mornfall.net/hashed-storage/0.5/Bundled/sha2.h) and [sha2.c](http://repos.mornfall.net/hashed-storage/0.5/Bundled/sha2.c) from hashed-storage, replace `hashed_storage_` with `darcs_` in both files, and change the FFI import in src/Crypt/SHA256.hs in darcs to:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "sha2.h darcs_sha256" c_sha256
    :: Ptr CChar -> CSize -> Ptr Word8 -> IO ()
```

I'd be happy to release darcs 2.8.3 with this change if it would help you. For 2.10 I'll switch to using cryptohash as above as I don't see any reason to keep using the local C version and in general in darcs we are trying to get rid of private implementations of common code.

EDIT: I originally thought hashed-storage would have the same problem, but I was wrong (in retrospect it's obvious that it would have clashed with darcs itself if not for the renaming).

Comment: I agree that using cryptohash is preferable for the long run but can live with the simpler fix for the moment if you prefer it for 2.8. An upload to Hackage would be great so I can use a released version. Thanks!