# Resolving GHC 'I found a duplicate definition for symbol ...'

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

When running Haskell programs that import several packages like this one:

```
import Text.Feed.Import 
import Network.HTTP

main = do
        page <- simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://stackoverflow.com")
        print $ page
```

I get an error like this one (*Note:* This question intends to solve the general problem, this specific case is just an example) :

```
GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol get_current_timezone_seconds
whilst processing object file
   /usr/lib/ghc/time-1.4.0.1/HStime-1.4.0.1.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry
```

Reinstalling the packages (e.g. `HTTP` and `feed` in the above case) as described [in this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258259/bytestring-linking-in-ghc) doesn't help. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Why this error occurs**

This issue is not specific to a single package (e.g. it was described [here](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/6) in relation to Yesod three years ago), but is caused by the different libraries you import (e.g. `HTTP` and `feed`) linking to different versions of a single library (this issue occurs only for libraries that export C-style symbols. Their symbol names are not unique. `time` is one of those packages.).

As denoted in the error message, the library that causes the issues in this specific case is `time-1.4.0.1`.

**Diagnosing the exact problem**

First, you need to identify which different versions exist of your library. You can do this by checking the packages using `ghc-pkg describe <packagename>`, or just take a look into your `cabal` installation directory (usually `~/.cabal/lib`).

At the time of writing this, the issue was caused by both `time-1.4.0.1` and `time-1.4.1` being installed. By using `ghc-pkg describe` I figured out that `feed` (and only `feed`, in my case), linked to `time-1.4.1` whereas about 100 libraries linked to `time-1.4.0.1`.

**How to resolve**

Identify the library version (of the library that causes the error, as denoted in the error message) as described above that fewer packages depend on. You'll need to rebuild all packages that depend on it. In my case this is `time-1.4.1`.

Then, uninstall the package:

```
$ ghc-pkg unregister time-1.4.1 --force 
unregistering time-1.4.1 would break the following packages: feed-0.3.9.2 (ignoring)
```

Note that the `feed` package is now broken and needs to be rebuilt and reinstalled. After rebuilding however, it won't link to `time-1.4.1` but `time-1.4.0.1` (in my specific case). This re-linking will resolve the duplicate symbol problem.

```
$ cabal install feed
```

If the error still occurs after that, re-check all dependencies as described above. You need to make sure any library you import will show the same library it's linked to when analyzed with `ghc-pkg describe <pkg>`

**Update:** In order to find out, which packages depend on the problematic library, simply use `ghc-pkg unregister` without the `--force` flag (Thanks to [John J. Camilleri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98600/john-j-camilleri) for pointing that out!). Note that if no packages depend on said problematic package, it will be removed.

Comment: Or you could use a sandboxed build to ensure that each package gets a consistent set of deps.

Comment: In order to find out what packages depend on the problematic library, simply use `ghc-pkg unregister` without the `--force` flag.

Comment: Thanks @JohnJ.Camilleri for pointing that out, I added that to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative cause of the same problem, is when using common symbols in an external library, on windows. I have an issue with a fortran code base using the `common` symbols. It is better explained here> https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/6107

This only happens in dynamic linking, so ghc works, but ghci does not.