# GHCI: I found a duplicate definition for symbol _fps_count

Tags: haskell, cabal

**tl;dr:** It seems like `Network.HTTP` and `Data.Aeson` are not compatible with each other. How would I begin working around this?

**Long version:** I think I narrowed this down as much as possible. I started with a fresh cabal sandbox and now am getting a runtime linker fatal error.

Here's my code:

```
-- test.hs
import Network.HTTP (simpleHTTP, getRequest, getResponseBody, postRequestWithBody)
import Data.Aeson

main = print "hi"
```

And here's how I get the error, from the very first command:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
$ cabal sandbox init
...
$ cabal install aeson
...
$ cabal repl
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :load test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> main
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package primitive-0.5.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package vector-0.10.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package text-0.11.3.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package parsec-3.1.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package unix-2.6.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package network-2.4.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-time-1.1.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package HTTP-4000.2.8 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.4.0 ... 

GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   _fps_count
whilst processing object file
   /Users/tapwater/p/haskell/stellar/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3/bytestring-0.10.4.0/libHSbytestring-0.10.4.0.a
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

If I comment out either one of the import statements, everything works fine.

Am I (hopefully) doing something wrong? Or are these two libraries entirely incompatible?

Comment: To answer the incompatibility: Two libraries cannot be incompatible except when they link to different versions of the same package, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272056/resolving-ghc-i-found-a-duplicate-definition-for-symbol).

Comment: Your packages directly or indirectly depend on two different versions of bytestring. You really shouldn't reinstall bytestring ever for any given version of GHC - it is just begging for trouble.  Delete your current `.ghc` and re-install the packages with a common version of bytestring.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson After I delete `.ghc`, how do I reinstall bytestring? Do I just install that package? Would other libraries know to use that version?

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being the solution:

```
$ cabal install http
```

I'm guessing this solved it because of cabal sandbox. I guess I need to do this for any library that comes with haskell platform that causes conflicts like this? I feel like I'm still doing something wrong.