# Cabal: rebuild package to use newer libraries

Tags: haskell

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 with GHC 7.6.3 and cabal installed via the Ubuntu package installer, and trying to use the [Heap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/heap-0.5.0/docs/Data-Heap.html) data structure, which I naively installed using:

```
cabal install heap
```

As soon as I started importing the library into my code, I got the following linking error:

```
...
Loading package primitive-0.5.0.1 ... linking ... done.
...
Loading package heap-1.0.0 ... linking ... done.
...
Loading package primitive-0.5.2.1 ... linking ... done
...

GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   hsprimitive_memset_Word32
whilst processing object file
   /home/simon/.cabal/lib/primitive-0.5.2.1/ghc-7.6.3/HSprimitive-0.5.2.1.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272056/resolving-ghc-i-found-a-duplicate-definition-for-symbol) notionally explains what to do, but the instructions are not specific enough  for me to follow.

How do I get Heap to use primitive-0.5.2.1 (I'm assuming that this lightly used library is the one that is out of date), or should I be doing something completely different?

Comment: I assume you are not using `cabal` for building your code. Using `cabal` and its sandboxing capability is the best way to avoid this problem.

Comment: I simply typed `cabal install heap` and ended up with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be to specifically install an earlier version of `heap`:

```
cabal install heap-0.6.0
```

You might have to first unregister heap-1.0.0.

Another option is to blow away your ~/.ghc directory. Of course, you will have to reinstall cabal packages.

I think the best option is to start using cabal sandboxing for your projects.

Edit: heap-1.0.0 contains QuickCheck tests and thus brings in all of the QuickCheck dependencies. To install that version without QuickCheck, try this:

1. In a new directory, run `cabal get heap-1.0.0`
2. `cd heap-1.0.0`
3. Edit `heap.cabal` and remove the `Build-Depends:` line
4. Run `cabal install`

Comment: Theres also the `nix` option if you really want it (the package manager). I don't use it myself, but I've heard much better things compared to sandboxes.

Comment: OK, `ghc-pkg unregister heap` and using 0.6 seems to work, but I have no idea why older code uses a new library. Is there any easy way of using 1.0.0?

Comment: added details on how to install version 1.0.0

Comment: Some advice on how to avoid cabal hell: [link](http://softwaresimply.blogspot.com/2014/07/haskell-best-practices-for-avoiding.html)